# How to find out x/y shift of two raster layers?

Tags: r, gis, raster, arcgis, qgis

regarding two raster layers which do not match exactly because of defective data, i would like to know, how to find out about the x/y shift between these two layers to align them properly using raster::shift()

i have already tried to investigate on the x/y-shift using qgis, but i just found the georeferencing tool, providing to relocate raster layers but not something interactive. i am looking for a possibility to move my defective raster on a basemap and getting information about the x/y shift.

i am **NOT** looking for a solution where i have to set specific georeferencing points to align the two raster layers since i am working on a highly dynamic landscape where it is difficult to find matching points, but where it is possible to align the raster layers by textural information provided by the datasets.

a code example should look like the solution provided by user @dTanMan URL:https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/77712/dtanman in this post URL:https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/201750

```
raster <- raster()
raster <- shift(raster, x=5, y=-15)
```

thanks a lot in advance, cheers, ExploreR

Comment: Can you provide the rasters? what "textual information" do you have? Because apart from matching points I do not see how you can achieve it

Comment: unfortunately i cannot provide a raster dataset. but just imagine a riverdelta, where sandbanks and riversides could change very often and you do not have any geopoints where you know for sure that they are constant in time. nevertheless i need to accurately locate my raster dataset. i could imagine, that there is kind of a function in arcgis or qgis, where you shift the raster on the basemap till it is fitting. you do not use single points, but more the structual information of the image to allign it, e.g. rivers, patches of vegetation, etc.

Comment: i could also imagine to polygonize or segment the raster dataset as well as the basemap, to calculate centroids of the polygons, number them from the upper left to the lower right and calculate the average distance for every point to its sibling point for x and y. then i could go on with raster::shift()

Comment: I don't know any function to do that, maybe as on https://gis.stackexchange.com where you have experts on GIS softwares

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use something like this

Example data

```
library(raster)
a <- raster(ncol=20, nrow=20, xmn=0,xmx=20,ymn=0,ymx=20)
values(a) <- 1:400
set.seed(3)
b <- a + runif(400)
```

Function to compare similarity of cell values

```
rmse <- function(obs, prd) {
    sqrt(mean((obs-prd)^2, na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Values from reference raster. May need to take a sample if raster is very large

```
nsamples <- 10000
s <- sampleRegular(a, nsamples, cells=TRUE)
sample_a <- s[,2]
```

Locations to be compared

```
xy <- xyFromCell(a, s[,1])
```

Test range for cell shifts

```
xrange <- -5:5 * xres(a)
yrange <- -5:5 * yres(a)
```

Matrix to store the results in

```
result <- cbind(rep(xrange, each=length(yrange)), rep(yrange, length(xrange)), NA)
colnames(result) <- c("dx", "dy", "rmse")
```

Loop over cellshift combinations

```
i <- 1
for (dx in xrange) {
    for (dy in yrange) {
        x <- shift(b, dx, dy)
        sample_b <- extract(x, xy)
        result[i,3] <- rmse(sample_a, sample_b)
        i <- i + 1
    }
}
```

Results suggest that dx=0 and dy=0 is the best in this case.

```
r <- result[order(result[,3]), ]
head(r)
#     dx dy      rmse
#[1,]  0  0 0.5734866
#[2,]  1  0 0.5800670
#[3,] -1  0 1.5252878
#[4,]  2  0 1.5302921
#[5,] -2  0 2.5153573
#[6,]  3  0 2.5157728
```

Test

```
bb <- shift(b, dx=r[1,1], dy=r[1,2])
rmse(values(a), values(bb))
#[1] 0.5734866
```

Comment: i found another solution you and your colleagues provided with RStoolbox::coregisterImages() (see URL:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStoolbox/RStoolbox.pdf) Thanks a lot for your help!